# The regularity of elliptic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-equations

Define 
$$ Lu:=-\partial_j(a_{ij}\partial_iu)+b_i\partial_iu+cu $$
where $a_{ij}$, $b_i$, and $c$ are all of $C^\infty(\bar \Omega)$ and we assume $\Omega$ is open bounded in $R^N$, smooth boundary, $N\geq 2$. Also, here $A=(a_{ij})$ satisfies uniformly elliptic condition, i.e., $A\xi\xi\geq\theta \,|\xi|^2$

We consider the standard PDE
\begin{cases}
Lu=f&x\in\Omega\\
u=0&x\in\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
Then by regularity, we have if $f\in C^\infty(\bar \Omega)$, then $u\in C^\infty(\bar \Omega)$ as well. However, if in addition we assume that $f$ is analytic, could I have $u$ is analytic as well? If yes, where can I find a proof?

Secondly, unless we are in one dimension, we know that if $f\in C^2(\bar\Omega)$, we may not have $u\in C^4(\bar\Omega)$(this is why we need Sobolev and Holder space). But could anybody provide me a counterexample? Thank you!

Comment: For the first question, you need to assume that $a_{ij}$, $b_i$ and $c$ are also analytic.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Thank you sir. But could you point out where I can find a prove for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, the answer can be found in paper [1] and references therein.

The answer for your second question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304065/counterexample-for-the-solvability-of-delta-u-f-for-f-in-c2/304073#304073).

[1]: Morrey, C. B., Jr.; Nirenberg, L. On the analyticity of the solutions of linear elliptic systems of partial differential equations.
Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 10 (1957), 271–290.

Comment: You are welcome @wisher. Note that the paper cited above, shows analitycity even in points of the boundary, if the boundary itself is analytic.

Comment: thank you! It looks to me if the data and coff are good enough, then the solution will be good as well, or even better, in some suitable space.